# Want to convert aspx page to html and send it via email in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have got the html part of my aspx page and now i need to send the string as email. The problem is the textbox values are not getting saved. Can any1 give me some ideas. Thank You

Here is my code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         StringBuilder sbOut = new StringBuilder();
         StringWriter swOut = new StringWriter(sbOut);
         HtmlTextWriter htwOut = new HtmlTextWriter(swOut);
         base.Render(htwOut);
         string sOut = sbOut.ToString();

         // Send sOut as an Email

         writer.Write(sOut);



         MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(txt_From.Text, txt_To.Text);
         msg.Subject = txt_Subject.Text;
         msg.Body =Sout.ToString();
         msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

         SmtpClient yourSmptpclient = new SmtpClient("10.238.52.900");
         try
         {
             yourSmptpclient.Send(msg);
         }
         catch (Exception Exp)
         {
             throw Exp;
         }
     }
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in before you send the email, and then use the html visualizer to have a look at the object holding the html.  Check if the textboxes are populated there.  In your case the `Sout` object.

Comment: on a side note, you are setting your subject twice :P

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, message);
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("localhost");
client.Send(mail);
```

Note that I set the mail message html to true: *mail.IsBodyHtml = true;* So, Now write your HTML code over the message variable and try. This will help you to send HTML page as an email.

Hope you're clear now.

Comment: How does this help the question?

Comment: I edited the code. the Sout is a variable which holds html.I need to pass this variable while sending the mail. When i do that i am getting just the border of my image. The textbox values are not getting saved. Am new to programming. Any tips or related links will help. Thank you

Comment: The point is i need the whole aspx page in the body of the mail.

Comment: I do not know how this got 3votes up?  It doesnt help the question at all.  He knows how to send it, just that the result doesn't display the values in the textboxes..

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems you are facing a problem while [Capture the ASPX content](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2004/Jun/08/Capturing-Output-from-ASPNet-Pages)

Please go through it.

Comment: i should use an external lib for that 'wwUtils'. Is there any other way to do it